# How to take and save multiple screenshots in the same Word file

Tags: automated-testing

I want to take multiple screenshots and save them in the same Word file as part of my test automation.

For Example:

I have an online book and I want to take screenshot of each page and save each screenshot in a Word file to use the check that the publishing process worked correctly.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you tell me what Automation tool are you using & in which language, and what code have to tried yourself.

Comment: How to ask a question on this forum. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To save info to a MS Word file, I would expect you have to use MSFT technologies. Easiest would be VBA - VisualBasic for Applications, internal scripting language for Word. You need to investigate how to make screenshots, or call some external tools from VBA. Which might be complex task.

Are you sure that you have to create Word text files in automated mode? I would suggest to reconsider: easiest would be to create HTML pages with linked images (using any scripting language, like Python).

Another option would be to create OpenOffice text files, I haven't looked but Java should have libraries for that.

Yet another option would be to invest time into C#, which is MSFT technology (should have libraries to work with Word) but has also Selenium binding (to automate browser actions).